# How to display viewCount YoutubeApi 3

Tags: youtube-api, view

I've got this code, I've try to change a little bit with `var v = value.statistics.viewCount;` but nothing work for me, I've try to find a answer but without any result...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $( $grid ).masonry( 'reloadItems' );
  $( $grid ).masonry( 'layout' );
 $('.add1').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var searchTerm = $('#query').val();
        getRequest(searchTerm);
  
  
    });
});

function getRequest(searchTerm) {
    url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search';
    var params = {
        part: 'snippet',
        key: 'AIzaSyA8OmKcw2DMNkJicyCJ0vqvf90xgeH52zE',
        q: searchTerm,
  maxResults:10
    };
  
    $.getJSON(url, params, function (searchTerm) {
        showResults(searchTerm);
    });
}

function showResults(results) {
    var html = "";
    var entries = results.items;
    
    $.each(entries, function (index, value) {
        var title = value.snippet.title;
        var thumbnail = value.snippet.thumbnails.high.url;
  var v = value.statistics.viewCount;
  
  var description = value.snippet.description;
  var videoID = value.id.videoId;
     
        html += '<div  class="item"  title="' + title + '">' + '<img class= "vidth" id="' + videoID + '" src="' + thumbnail + '" ><div class="info"><p1>' + title+'</p1><hr><p2>'+description+'</p2><hr><p3>'+v+'</p3></div></div>';
    }); 
    $('.masonry').append(html);
 $( $grid ).masonry( 'reloadItems' );
$( $grid ).masonry( 'layout' );
 
}
```

any ideas ?

Comment: there is no `viewCount` and search list ressource, check the api

Comment: seriously no idea ? could You please help with it ?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35615051/2274530 the code retrieve viewCount from all video in a playlist

Answer (score 0):

1. You are trying to get viewCount from the statistics part, but you only queried for the snippet part.
2. You can only query for the statistics from the videos.list endpoint - it is not available through the search endpoint.

You will have to take the ids from the search results and then do a videos.list query for those ids to get the statistics on each and therefore the viewCount. See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list